# Scale factor evolution for positive curvature universe

Tags: cosmology, spacetime

From the Friedmann equations we can write
$$\dot{a}^2=H_0^2\left(\Omega_{R,0}a^{-2}+\Omega_{M,0}a^{-1}+(1-\Omega_0)+\Omega_{\Lambda,0}a^2\right).$$
Typically, one takes the square root of both sides and for $\Omega_0\leq 1$ this differential equation can be solved to obtain $a(t)$ (sometimes of course requiring numerics).

For $\Omega_0>1$, however, this leads us to a solution where $a(t)$ is now complex. I think I've missed something crucial but I can't seem to find it. How do I make sense of the complex solution?

Comment: Could you show us how you obtain $\int\frac{H_0^{-1}ada}{\sqrt{\Omega_{R,0}+\Omega_{M,0}a+(1-\Omega_0)a^2+\Omega_{\Lambda,0}a^4}}$ as complex-valued for $\Omega_0>1$?

Comment: E.g.  if $\Omega_{R,0}=0$ and $\Omega_{\Lambda,0}=0$ then: $$ \int \frac{H_0^{-1} a da}{\sqrt{\Omega_{M,0}a +(1-\Omega_0)a^2 }}$$ has a complex denominator for large enough values of $a$ given that $1-\Omega_0<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's discuss your example $\Omega_{R,0}=\Omega_{\Lambda,0}=0$, viz.$$\int H_0dt=\pm\int\frac{ada}{\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_{M,0}^2}{4(\Omega_0-1)}-(\Omega_0-1)\left(a-\frac{\Omega_{M,0}}{2(\Omega_0-1)}\right)^2}}.$$If $\Omega_{M,0}>0,\,\Omega_0>1$, the substitution$$a=\frac{\Omega_{M,0}}{2(\Omega_0-1)}(1+\sin\theta)$$obtains$$\int H_0dt=\pm\int\frac{\Omega_{M,0}}{2(\Omega_0-1)^{3/2}}\left(1+\sin\theta\right)\operatorname{sgn}(\cos\theta)d\theta.$$We must enforce $\theta\in\Bbb R$, so in a positive-curvature universe $a$ is capped.